# October CMS - Can't Send Email Using Templates

Tags: laravel, email, phpmailer, octobercms

I work with the lastest version of october and I encountered a problem.

When I send a mail using the base october system (templates) I don't receive it. I mean, even if i use the button "Send Test Message" I see the confirmation popup but anything is received in my inbox.

That's strange because I am using that method since september and everything worked fine, I think it could be the lastest update (build 431) that broke it.

I really need a solution for this, thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. If you have problems with your CMS, check your log files, ask the CMS maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your previous mail build but now in new build there are some changes they have made.

> if you are using default `mail` method they have removed it as `swiftmailer`  has also removed it. (as October Cms also using `swiftmailer`)

please read this github issue : https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/3256

so now you need to use `smtp` or `sendmail` method.

in above article `github issue` they described how you can use new `sendmail` method this may help you.